# csv file has no nulls, only has some column values that are zero(0). But when i import from csv file to postgres, why do they seem null, not zero?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I don't want to give up learning sql, python etc. But i came across basic problems so I can't move on.

I want to analyse things using SQL commands. But I can't even upload csv files correctly.

Comment: What is in the fiel? How did you try to read it?

Comment: I just opened to csv file to see whats in column. Its zero, not null. But when i imported from csv file to postgres, they are null, not zero... Now im trying to make them zero, by this code "UPDATE table SET column= 0 WHERE column IS NULL;"  etc.

Comment: Please post a sample of the cvs file, describe the fields you say contain 0 and the corresponding null table columns. Also, how did you try to import it?

Comment: @Belayer thank you for the reply. I just solved it by updating column and filling null values with 0. But i didnt understand why i got that problem. I import from pgadmin, choosing the column, by right click, and select import.

Comment: Based on the level of detail you include, I can't really say more than "works for me".

Comment: "choosing the column, by right click, and select import. "  You import into tables, not columns.  (You can select specific columns of a table to import, the rest getting their default values, but that is an advanced feature and you don't describe doing so.)  Which pgadmin are you using: 3 or 4?

Comment: @jjanes well i am new to SQL, as well as pgadming world. I dont know what i got that error, but i solved it by changing with zero which were null. And i am using pgadmin4